# nested while loop outputs only one row to select tag in php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I am using the below code to retrieve data in my page to select tag

```
<?php
     $approveduser = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `status` ='approved' AND `id` != '" . $_SESSION['user_row_id'] . "'");

    while ($approvedrow = mysqli_fetch_array($approveduser)) { 
    //this loops works fine
  ?>
        <tr>
           <td class="text-center">
              <div class="">
                  <select id="cat">
                     <?php
                         $cityquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `cities`");

                         while ($cityquery = mysqli_fetch_array($cityquery)) {
                         //this loop has the problem
                     ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $cityquery['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cityquery['cityname']; ?></option>
                    <?php    
                     }
                    ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
       <?php
       }
     ?>
```

My second while loop  outputs only one line to the select tag when there are more rows in the database.
What can be the error causing this.
How can I fix this.

Comment: Fetch the contents of `cities` first and store the results on an array. Then you can reuse that array in the inner loop instead of querying the exact same data from the database over and over again.

Comment: As an extension to what @MagnusEriksson says, you could build the whole select HTML in a string and then just output it for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is you overwrite the `$cityquery` variable with the row. Use a separate variable for the row.

```
  <select id="cat">
     <?php
         $cityquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `cities`");

         while ($cityrow = mysqli_fetch_array($cityquery)) {
         //this loop has the problem
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $cityrow['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cityrow['cityname']; ?></option>
    <?php    
     }
    ?>
  </select>
```

The above will work but it would be better to get the cities into a single array, as opposed to fetching them within a loop.